# Blocking many disjoint IP addresses

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, iptables

I'm looking for the right tool to block a fairly large number (~1000s) of IP addresses from contacting my server. The application is very latency sensitive, so the blocking needs to occur directly on the server, rather than putting it behind a secondary application.

I've seen various posts that suggest either iptables or ufw (I'm using ubuntu), however all the examples I can find are dealing with the case of blocking a single IP, or a range of IPs. Unfortunately, very few of the blocking IPs fall within a small ranges, and there many other valid connections that come from within wider ranges. While I could write some scripts to manage these tools, I'd like to see if there were existing tools out there that handle this use case well.

Thanks.

Comment: `ipset` may be what you're looking for

Comment: As roaima mentions, ipset https://ipset.netfilter.org/ will likely help.

Comment: Thanks, I looked at this tool and it appears to fit my use case well!

Answer (score 0):

Beside comments under question there is `ufw` on Ubuntu:

Example command:

`sudo ufw deny proto tcp from 202.54.1.0/24 to any port 22`